# Why does my Linux server hang with "ps aux"

Tags: ps, sles

I have a server running scientific computation applications. It is SLES 11sp3.

Here are some of my observations:

1. I could login to the server with ssh.
2. But for some reason I don't understand, when I run command like `ps aux` it will hang.
3. However, the command `top` is fine and here is the output:

   ```
   top - 21:02:49 up 403 days,  5:36,  5 users,  load average: 21.01, 20.31, 18.79
   Tasks: 271 total,   6 running, 241 sleeping,  24 stopped,   0 zombie
   Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  6.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 49.9%id, 43.8%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
   Mem:    258428M total,   156884M used,   101543M free,        0M buffers
   Swap:     7999M total,     2588M used,     5411M free,   151700M cached

      PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S   %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                           
    39993 root      20   0  9064 1276  824 R      0  0.0   0:00.43 top                                                                                
        1 root      20   0 10548   68   36 S      0  0.0   5:24.51 init                                                                               
        2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:06.20 kthreadd                                                                                3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   5:17.22 ksoftirqd/0                                                                        
        6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0  51:15.16 migration/0                                                                             8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   4:39.14 migration/1                                                                        
       10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   1:30.39 ksoftirqd/1                                                                            13 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   1:34.02 migration/2                                                                        
       15 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:16.03 ksoftirqd/2                                                                            17 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   1:19.64 migration/3                                                                        
       19 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:13.99 ksoftirqd/3                                                                            21 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   1:44.44 migration/4                                                                        
       23 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:18.40 ksoftirqd/4                                                                            25 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   1:42.13 migration/5                                                                        
       26 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0  14:56.25 kworker/5:0                                                                            27 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:18.18 ksoftirqd/5                                                                        
       29 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   1:43.97 migration/6                                                                            30 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0  12:30.00 kworker/6:0                                                                        
       31 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:15.76 ksoftirqd/6                                                                            33 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   1:41.60 migration/7                                                                        
       35 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:12.94 ksoftirqd/7                                                                            37 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   5:13.03 migration/8                                                                        
       39 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   1:05.10 ksoftirqd/8                                                                            41 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R      0  0.0   3:35.18 migration/9                                                                        
       43 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:45.77 ksoftirqd/9                                                                            44 root      RT   0     0    0    0 R      0  0.0   2:21.35 watchdog/9                                                                         
       45 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   3:14.10 migration/10                                                                           46 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0  25:52.76 kworker/10:0                                                                       
       47 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:29.33 ksoftirqd/10                                                                           48 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   2:11.92 watchdog/10                                                                        
       49 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   3:03.78 migration/11                                                                           51 root      20   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   0:29.36 ksoftirqd/11                                                                       
       52 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   2:09.54 watchdog/11                                                                            53 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S      0  0.0   3:13.56 migration/12
   ```
4. Some further detail about the server:

   ```
   # cat /etc/SuSE-release 
   SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
   VERSION = 11
   PATCHLEVEL = 3

   # uname -a
   Linux n049 3.0.76-0.11-default #1 SMP Fri Jun 14 08:21:43 UTC 2013 (ccab990) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
   ```
5. I tried to write to the procfs by:

   ```
   echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog
   ```

   It also hangs without response.

I would like to know what's the possible reason for this type of problem.

**EDIT:** As per @Mat's suggestion, I have also posted the output from the following commands:

**iostat**

```
Linux 3.0.76-0.11-default (n049)    03/01/2016  _x86_64_

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          79.98    0.00    0.35    0.25    0.00   19.41

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               2.46        38.15       845.71 1329385997 29467274973
```

**nfsstat**

```
Client rpc stats:
calls      retrans    authrefrsh
544779536   157        544901831

Client nfs v3:
null         getattr      setattr      lookup       access       readlink     
0         0% 296447353 54% 17723933  3% 6435727   1% 44311228  8% 204       0% 
read         write        create       mkdir        symlink      mknod        
47603223  8% 122630268 22% 750048    0% 45661     0% 4         0% 0         0% 
remove       rmdir        rename       link         readdir      readdirplus  
509509    0% 42896     0% 5249      0% 198       0% 0         0% 856848    0% 
fsstat       fsinfo       pathconf     commit       
15677     0% 22716     0% 11358     0% 7380246   1%
```

**panfs_stat /projects/**

```
opstats timestamp: 1456830706:536977000

PanFS Client Exported Opstats
    callback__breaks        806486
    callback__break_all     4
    callback__cancels       8389
    ioctl__getattr          0
    ioctl__setattr          0
    op__device_create       30
    op__dir_create          72765
    op__dir_delete          3389
    op__dir_fmlookup        2913280
    op__dir_lookup          4415755
    op__dir_fmreaddir       1457842
    op__file_create         1423833
    op__file_link_create    0
    op__file_delete         867145
    op__file_rename         59860
    op__file_silly_rename   4453
    op__getattr_total       36999003848
    op__ioctl               356581655
    op__llapi_sync          120384107
    op__read                552594596
    op__read__total_bytes   14363262382940
    op__sync                501053283
    op__sync__total_bytes   7978169577178
    op__symlink_create      0
    op__symlink_follow      3125353
    op__symlink_read        3550281
    op__setattr             65362728
    op__write               30887557434
    op__write__total_bytes  15818900301081
    op__write_retried       0
    op__writepage           411
PanFS Syscall Opstats
    close       suc 262891996 / unsuc   396 / started 262892393  longest 37:592322933 / 0:000578105  avg 0:000151250 / 0:000061983
    create      suc 1423829 / unsuc     5 / started 1423834  longest 185:525407516 / 0:007318163  avg 0:009095410 / 0:002275271
    fsync       suc   425 / unsuc     0 / started   425  longest 0:961370596 / 0:000000000  avg 0:070172226 / 0:000000000
    getattr     suc 491151434 / unsuc     1 / started 491151435  longest 48:897901802 / 0:039782489  avg 0:000001457 / 0:039782489
    getxattr    suc  6516 / unsuc  9640 / started 16156  longest 0:000270379 / 0:000034562  avg 0:000006670 / 0:000000955
    ioctl       suc     1 / unsuc 356582148 / started 356582150  longest 0:000008650 / 0:096541018  avg 0:000008650 / 0:000000963
    link        suc     0 / unsuc     0 / started     0  longest 0:000000000 / 0:000000000  avg 0:000000000 / 0:000000000
    llseek      suc 741005516 / unsuc 1021903 / started 742027419  longest 0:279553783 / 0:000021232  avg 0:000000451 / 0:000000282
    lock        suc  1452 / unsuc     0 / started  1452  longest 0:016063605 / 0:000000000  avg 0:001258309 / 0:000000000
    lookup      suc 4415772 / unsuc     0 / started 4415772  longest 139:467332687 / 0:000000000  avg 0:010307139 / 0:000000000
    mkdir       suc 72765 / unsuc     0 / started 72765  longest 1:101200148 / 0:000000000  avg 0:003296509 / 0:000000000
    mknod       suc    30 / unsuc     0 / started    30  longest 0:159658010 / 0:000000000  avg 0:021141579 / 0:000000000
    mmap        suc 10953869 / unsuc     0 / started 10953869  longest 0:011133309 / 0:000000000  avg 0:000000688 / 0:000000000
    open        suc 262892479 / unsuc    16 / started 262892495  longest 244:019141374 / 0:171940090  avg 0:000008309 / 0:079117046
    permission  suc 4479767553 / unsuc 1975542 / started 4481743095  longest 148:505477264 / 2:209368229  avg 0:000001927 / 0:000035222
    put_super   suc  5464 / unsuc     0 / started  5464  longest 0:001834006 / 0:000000000  avg 0:000040821 / 0:000000000
    read        suc 552597080 / unsuc     1 / started 552597081  longest 193:103296270 / 0:012257444  avg 0:000047965 / 0:012257444
    readdir     suc 1664834 / unsuc    10 / started 1664844  longest 3:179359832 / 1:464181024  avg 0:003504540 / 0:155413678
    rename      suc 55407 / unsuc     0 / started 55407  longest 20:462678110 / 0:000000000  avg 0:008082163 / 0:000000000
    rmdir       suc  3153 / unsuc   236 / started  3389  longest 0:433589477 / 0:000464708  avg 0:002029711 / 0:000313255
    setattr     suc 65373798 / unsuc     0 / started 65373798  longest 243:868835310 / 0:000000000  avg 0:004721321 / 0:000000000
    setxattr    suc     0 / unsuc     0 / started     0  longest 0:000000000 / 0:000000000  avg 0:000000000 / 0:000000000
    statfs      suc   214 / unsuc     0 / started   214  longest 0:012208633 / 0:000000000  avg 0:000528460 / 0:000000000
    symlink     suc     0 / unsuc     0 / started     0  longest 0:000000000 / 0:000000000  avg 0:000000000 / 0:000000000
    unlink      suc 870893 / unsuc     0 / started 870893  longest 14:820432065 / 0:000000000  avg 0:001506087 / 0:000000000
    vfs_admit   suc     0 / unsuc     0 / started     0  longest 0:000000000 / 0:000000000  avg 0:000000000 / 0:000000000
    write       suc 30888837091 / unsuc     0 / started 30888838130  longest 1041:545276662 / 0:000000000  avg 0:000010204 / 0:000000000
```

**sar -n DEV**

```
Average:           lo      0.03      0.03      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
Average:         eth0      1.34      0.53      0.16      0.10      0.00      0.00      0.01
Average:         eth1      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
Average:          ib0      1.05      5.14      0.15      0.81      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

Comment: That's very low CPU and very high %WAIT for scientific computing. Trouble with your disks?

Comment: @Mat, The high %wait is a bit strange. It is using a parallel NFS, the file system is fine to access from the node and other nodes. Also to write to the /proc, should it be in memory? Also for "ps aux". will this command have any disk access?

Comment: `ps aux` mainly reads from /proc (apart from loading `ps` itself and its dependent libraries). `/proc` is all stored in memory in kernel space AFAIK. Is your network ok? (speed/duplex, perf tests on those NFS mounts?) Checked firmware levels compared to similar machines? Checked RAM health? (I have no idea about the issue, just random thoughts.)

Comment: @Mat Network is fine. I am running IB, and we have a RDMA throughput of  #bytes     #iterations    BW peak[MB/sec]    BW average[MB/sec]
 65536      1000           3271.42            3270.94

Comment: Try iostat, nfsstat and maybe iotop to try and see what's blocking. `sar -n DEV` could maybe give a clue too.

Comment: What does `cat /proc/sys/kernel/tainted` say?

Comment: @kasperd: cat /proc/sys/kernel/tainted 
3221225475

Comment: @kasperd, how should I interpret the tainted value of 3221225475?

Comment: @Winston It is a set of flags, so you need to convert it to binary. In binary that number comes out as `11000000000000000000000000000011`, so the kernel has been tainted for four different reasons. You should start looking in the kernel log for additional information as to why it was tainted. And you should plan for a reboot in the near future. Be aware that the system may hang in case you attempt a clean shutdown, so plan to have hands on site when you try to reboot it.

Comment: @Winston Somewhere there exist a list of what each of the tainted bits mean. I'll write another comment if I find it. But you are likely to find more details by looking in the kernel log than what each of those bits could tell you.

Comment: @kasperd, the kernel taint is likely to be caused by our installation of the DirectFlow driver for Panasas PanFS. http://www.panasas.com/products/panfs/network-protocols

Comment: @Winston I found a list of taint codes indicating the two first indicate a license issue and a module forcible loaded onto an incompatible kernel version. The list I found is not complete, so it does not have the last two taint codes from your kernel.

Comment: @Winston In `linux/kernel.h` I found a list of taint codes going from 0 to 14. Your kernel has taint codes 0, 1, 30, and 31. You probably have to contact the author of that kernel module. I think that module is not supported on your kernel version.

Comment: @kasperd, thanks for pointing to the kernel taint. the demsg did show  there is CPU soft lockup caused by the kernel module for the PanFS driver.   There is some cpu lockup caused by a thread pool used internally.